# How to check for the rows continuity of an event in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help in Google Sheets to check for the continuity of an event which is a cell value say "3". The continuity needs to be checked for the last 7 cells. If the condition is satisfied (doesn't matter how many times) the value in the Result column is 1.

Please help in solving the problem.

Refer to the attached image for illustration.

[image]

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Continuity Checker

```
function continuityChecker() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() -1, 15).getValues()
  const o = vs.reduce((a, r, j) => {
    r.forEach((c, i) => {
      if (i == 0) { a.sum = 0; a.o.push([0]) }
      if (c){ a.sum++;}else{a.sum = 0;}
      if (a.sum == 7) a.o[a.o.length - 1] = [1];
    })
    return a;
  }, { o: [], sum: 0, output: function () { return this.o; } }).output();
  sh.getRange(2, 16, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Output:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | Result |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Try in ***P2***

```
=--ARRAYFORMULA(MAX((IFERROR({SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(A2:O2="",COLUMN(A2:N2),"")),"|"),16}-IFERROR({0,SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(A2:O2="",COLUMN(A2:N2),"")),"|")})-1)))>=7)
```

drag to bottom.

I've compared single cells with next, if different retrieve column number. Next create two array, shifiting the second to the right. The difference create the intervals of "3", using MAX check if exists the continuity that return TRUE or FALSE. The double minus transform that in 1 or 0 returning the value asked by OP

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TheMaster normally I don't see explanations and this led me to think that I shouldn't enter them except on request.
But I believe the observation to be correct, so I propose it:
I've compared single cells with next, if different retrieve column number. Next create two array, shifiting the second to the right. The difference create the intervals of "3", using MAX check if exists the continuity that return TRUE or FALSE.
The double minus transform that in 0 or 1 returning the value asked by OP

Comment: Terio, Yes many provide only code, but it's bad practice. The link in my previous comment shows consensus among users.

Comment: @Terio The solution works fine for the above-stated problem. But I get into trouble when the number of columns gets more. For example- values in cells are spread from A2:X2 and results are posted in Y2. Then the result always is "1". Though it is not satisfying the continuity condition. Any help in this, I tried to change the code with my basic understanding which is `=--ARRAYFORMULA(MAX((IFERROR({SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(A2:X2="",COLUMN(A2:W2),"")),"|"),25}-IFERROR({0,SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(A2:X2="",COLUMN(A2:W2),"")),"|")})-1)))>=7)`

Comment: @HawfinchTaylor if you share an example sheet, easy with GS, can I try to solve them and show the solution in the sheet also